# Apche http mod_rewrite and HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.2, https, mod-rewrite, 301-redirect

I have two domains `old.example` and `new.example`.

I want to redirect `old.example` to `new.example` sending a `301` response code and forcing to use https.

All works fine using HTTP, but it fails with HTTPS. i.e. if I enter `http://old.example` address in browser changes to `https://new.example`.

But if I enter `https://old.example` nothing changes and navigation proceeds using `https://old.example`.

Below there configuration files both for HTTP and HTTPS.
Apache version is 2.2.15 (Unix)

Anyone can help me to understand the problem?

**http.conf:**

```
VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName   192.0.2.11
   ServerAlias  old.example www.old.example new.example www.new.example

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log"
   RewriteLogLevel 3
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =old.example
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.example$1 [R=permanent,L]

   SecRuleEngine Off

   ProxyRequests off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   <Proxy *>
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
   ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

   <Location />
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**httpd-le-ssl.conf:**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName   192.0.2.11
   ServerAlias  old.example www.old.example new.example www.new.example

   SSLEngine on
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite-ssl.log"
   RewriteLogLevel 3
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =old.example
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.example$1 [R=permanent,L]


   SecRuleEngine Off

   ProxyRequests off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   <Proxy *>
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
   ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

   <Location />
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
   </Location>

   Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/old.example/cert.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/old.example/privkey.pem
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/old.example/chain.pem
```

Comment: Apache 2.2 is _very_ EOL. You should upgrade to v. 2.4, and, after you do, you will also find that what you want to accomplish is actually  _much_ easier and, potentially, less resource consuming.

Comment: In any case, for the same reason, this question is off-topic on Server Fault.

Comment: @Colt I agree with you that is an old version, but it has all features to reach the goal we need.

Comment: While Apache 2.2 may _have_ all of the features that you want, what it _does not have_ is any evaluation, let alone patch, for any of the **twenty-six** security vulnerabilities that have been addressed in Apache 2.4 in the time since version 2.2 went EOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =old.example
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.example$1 [R=permanent,L]
> ```

It's not clear why these directives would not redirect `https://old.example`. However, it's not strictly correct and can be immediately simplified. For instance, it certainly won't redirect `www.old.example` as you are explicitly checking for `old.example` (an exact match) only (this also applies to the port 80 vHost). You should check that it is *not* `new.example` (the canonical hostname) instead.

Checking the `HTTPS` server variable inside the host for port 443 is entirely superfluous.

So, this can be rewritten as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=new.example
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.example$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

However, you should consider splitting your old-domain into a separate vHost and implementing a simple mod_alias `Redirect` instead of using mod_rewrite here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the help.

The problem was that section below was duplicated in another files.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

</VirtualHost>
```

However I accepted @MrWhite solution because he suggested two improvement in configuration: splitting each domain in a separate vHost and to remove `HTTPS` server variable.

Thanks